# Online Latin version of the "Crater Hermetis"

Tags: latin-language, crater-hermetis, ludovico-lazzarelli

Is there a Latin version of the *Crater Hermetis* by Ludovico Lazzarelli available online?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is available on [Archive.org](https://archive.org/details/ita-bnc-mag-00000928-001/page/n132/mode/2up). It is part of a volume printed in 1505 with this long title:

> Contenta in hoc volumine. Pimander. Mercurij Trismegisti liber De sapiential et potestate dei. Asclepius. Eiusdem Mercurij liber De voluntate diuina. Item Crater Hermetis a Lazarelo Septempedano.

That translates to:

> The contents of this volume. Pimander. Mercury Thrice-Majestic's Book of the Wisdom and Power of God. Asclepius. The same Mercury's book On the Free Will of God. Also Crater Hermetis by Lazarelo Septempedano.

(Translation mine, so iffy.)

I guess Hermes Trismegistus is "Mercury Thrice-Majestic" and the book is an anthology of works about or attributed to him?

Comment: To whomever pointed me to Archive.org, thanks! Exactly what I was looking for. And I can't believe I didn't think to look there. I've found several books like this on that website. And it has so much other stuff. I graduated (BA) from Univ of Toronto, so get a kick out of seeing the contents of the UofT (Robarts) library.